# exact meaning of "same regions" regarding "Google Cloud Storage -> Network -> Data Transfer to Cloud services in the same Region"?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to know the exact meaning of "same regions" regarding "Google Cloud Storage -> Network -> Data Transfer to Cloud services in the same Region".

Some specific country means same regions?
I need more specific information about definition of same regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to:
https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing

This means that transfers are free of charge when going to Cloud Services within the Google infrastructure. It never leaves Google's network. For example, downloading from Cloud Storage to a Compute Engine.

If it leaves Google's network, then they will charge.